# $locationProvider isn't working in my Angular page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular page i'm using a `$locationProvider`. But it's not working in my web page. I got error in my console like this, *$location in HTML5 mode requires a  tag to be present!*. so i add a `<base href="/" />`, which also not working in my angular page. Here i mentioned my directory structure and my code.

Here my [sample Project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dk0bwuanc86xp7t/SampleApp.zip?dl=0) too. Help me out to resolve this problem.

**my directory structure**

```
 iwa (root directory)
  > js
      > lib
         -> angular.js
         -> angular.route.js
      -> app.js
  > views
      -> home.html
      -> about.html
 -> index.html
```

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="inQueueWeb">
 <head lang="en">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="js/lib/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
     <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </html>
```

**app.js**

```
  var iwa = angular.module('inQueueWeb', ['ngRoute']);

   iwa.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
   .when("/", {templateUrl: 'views/home.html'})
   .when("/rest", {templateUrl: 'views/about.html'});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

And also i tried these

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enable: true, requireBase: false});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. You've got to add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to your app's `.config()` method, and then add a `<base href="/">` to your HTML head. I think you've done this already.

What's going wrong is this: with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, a hashbang (`/#mypage`) URL isn't necessary. A URL would simply be `/mypage`, without the hash. You need to update the links in your `views/templates/header.html` to suit this.

I've updated:

- Your `app.js` to add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`.
- Your `index.html` to add `<base href="/">`, and
- Your `views/templates/header.html` to adjust the anchor links.

I hope this was helpful! You can [download an archive with the adjusted files here](http://ge.tt/98cFmHL2/v/0?c).

Comment: I'm already removed that hash in my `config` file. Not worked. Now I downloaded and checked that you provided project too. I was also not working. Project can't to download the css and js. I using Webstrom editor tool.

Comment: In that case, your directory structure is incorrect. The base href cannot be /. What is in your browser's address bar while viewing the file?

Comment: The error was in your downloaded project. I didn't change any project structure. URL in addressbar http://localhost:63342/tejas/index.html.  In console, http://localhost:63342/js/lib/angular.min.js

Comment: Since my files are in a folder `tejas`, you'll need to update the base href to `<base href="/tejas/">`. That should do it. :)

Comment: Last time i tried this too. Not worked. But Now its worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I faced one more problem too. My web app is an responsive webpage. When i load it in moblie, it shows desktop version. Can you check it in mobile browser for me by using chrome?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84546/discussion-between-aniruth-and-tejas).

Answer (score 2):

Add this below your head tag

```
<base href="/">
```

Then under your router, add $locationProvider in your .config

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

Add this underneath all your .when states

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

$urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {
    var slashHashRegex,
        matches,
        path = $location.url();

    // check to see if the path already has a slash where it should be
    if (path[path.length - 1] === '/' || path.indexOf('/?') > -1) {
        return path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
    }

    // if there is a trailing slash *and* there is a hash, remove the last slash so the route will correctly fire
    slashHashRegex = /\/(#[^\/]*)$/;
    matches = path.match(slashHashRegex);
    if (1 < matches.length) {
        return path.replace(matches[0], matches[1]);
    }
});
```

Create an .htaccess file if you don't have one already, and add this ( assuming you are using index.html )

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Then there is a problem with your <base href="/">  - Please makes sure you have the correct path for that.  Normally your error in your console  refers to this.

Comment: @Satheesh Santhosh, did you figure out the problem by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will help you, but

```
!DOCTYPE html>
```

It should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Or did you make wrong copy while you are posting question?

Comment: i forgot to paste that. that's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

In the first place I'm missing the base tag in your index.html? Which you might have replaced with:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enable: true, requireBase: false});
```

Unfortunately, you made a little typo in 'enable'. Which should be 'enabled' (with an ending 'd'). So, fix the typo or add the base tag and change the $locationProvider line with:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I think that will solve the problem.

Besides all of this, you have to place the script between the < body >< /body > tags. Otherwise it's not valid HTML.

Comment: What kind of error do you have in the console? Is it still: $location in HTML5 mode requires a tag to be present! If yes, then there is still something wrong with your base tag. Could you update your question with the latest code changes (such as adding the base tag?) Because the current code would definitely not work.

Comment: before i didn't tried `$locationProvider`, i just copied these code and tried to get the solution. not working. Even i tried all the answers which under this question, nothing happened again. i'm search about this, most probably answers are similar to us. But i don't know why is not working me too. i didn't get any error in my console.